# git rebase not continuing after fixing conflicts

Tags: git, git-rebase

I ran a `git rebase origin/[branch]` on a branch that is the result of merging multiple local branches together during development. As expected I ran into some conflicts and began fixing them. The first several were fine. Git listed the files, I cleaned them up, did the appropriate `git add [file]` for each one and then did a `git rebase --continue` and on it went.

But now I've hit a patch that conflicted and is cleaned up but I can't continue for some reason. I've cleaned up the files and all of them are staged but when I `git rebase --continue` I get:

```
$ git rebase --continue
You must edit all merge conflicts and then
mark them as resolved using git add
```

I know for a fact this commit in question removes a file that was later re-added and modified. But when I `git status` all I see is:

```
$ git status
# Not currently on any branch.
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
# modified: [file 1]
# modified: [file 2]
# modified: [file 3]
#
```

The file that was deleted is not shown.

So there's no files left to modify but git insists I still have to do something else before I can continue on my way.

Answer (score 4):

Figured this problem out and putting this here in case anyone else encounters it:

I noticed the file that I thought was removed in this commit was still on the file system, and was being tracked by git still. So I did a `git rm [file]` on it and got the following message:

```
$ git rm [file one]
[file two]: needs merge
rm '[file one]'
```

When I checked `[file two]` sure enough it was still in a conflicted state and needed to be fixed. Upon fixing it up and staging I was able to `git rebase --continue`. I'm still not sure why the deleted file was not showing as deleted or why this file wasn't being shown as needing to be fixed when doing `git status` though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `git ls-files -u` to get the list of files git considers to be not merged.